# Does squareroot of a complex number have two different outputs?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

A function is defined as a mapping for which it is true that for every input there is exactly one output. Squareroot is a function. It is defined as the inverse function to the quadratic function. So why does a squareroot of a complex number nine have two outputs? They should be +3 and -3. I don't understand that. It is a contradiction to the definition of a function, ie to the part "... only one output."

Comment: "*Squareroot is a function*"  Correction: the *principal square root* is a function.  The one and only principal square root of $9$ is positive $3$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: It's a slight abuse of the term "function", but fairly standard so I guess there's nothing to do but get used to it

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^2$ isn't one-to-one, and hence isn't invertible.   It doesn't pass the horizontal line test.   Not every function does.

In complex analysis you learn about branches of the square root function.  Branch cuts are a way of dealing with certain multi-valued functions.

The theory of Riemann surfaces has to do with this phenomenon.